# tsql - Batch insert performance

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I would like to improve the speed of some inserts on an application I am working on.
I had originally created a batch like this:

```
insert tableA (field1, field2) values (1,'test1'), (2, 'test2')
```

This works great on SQL Server 2008 and above, but I need my inserts to work on SQL Server 2005.  My question is would I get any performance benefit using a batch like this:

```
insert tableA (field1, field2)
select 1, 'test1'
union all
select 2, 'test2'
```

Over this batch:

```
insert tableA (field1, field2) values (1, 'test1')
insert tableA (field1, field2) values (2, 'test2')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altough it may seem that less code to process should give you a performance gain, using first option (union all) is a bad idea.
All select statements have to be parsed and executed before the data is inserted into a table. It'll consume a lot of memory and may take forever to finish even for fairly small amount of data. On the other hand separate insert statements are executed "on the fly".

Run a simple test in SSMS that will prove this: create a simple table with 4 fields and try inserting 20k rows. Second solution will execute in seconds, while first... you'll see :).

Another problem is that when the data is not correct in som row (type mismatch for example), you'll receive an error like `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'x' to data type int.`, but you'll have no indication which row failed - you'd have to find it yourself. But with separate inserts, you'll know exactly which insert failed.